# How to create default template for js, css files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, myeclipse

How to create default template for .js, .css files as like we can create/customize templates for .java files in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on which plug-ins you use for development.

In core Eclipse, a solution could be to set the default template content. Go to `Web --> CSS Files --> Editor --> Templates`, and edit the `New CSS File` item for example.

Comment: Could i know, which eclipse plugin need to install to do this.

Comment: I'm using the Java EE Eclipse build with WTP (Web Tools Platform) installed, probably that's the one you're searching for.

Comment: thanks friend, i will try this, i am also using JEE Eclipse only. I search with 'web tools' and 'javascript' and 'css' in eclipse market place. but i am not getting any well known plugins, I am getting some thing i never hear. Can you please help me with name of plugin dear friend.

Comment: Glad to hear :-) Btw try searching under `Help --> Install new software...` too, because not all the available plugins are on the marketplace. Which are there though, are a bit easier to set up :-)